# CSS Cascade has no affect on font shorthand if properties have variables as values

Tags: css, web-component, css-variables

Let’s assume we have the following CSS Custom Properties:

```
// Global CSS
:root {
  --font-weight-500: 500;
  --font-size-350: 14px;
  --font-line-height-500: 20px;
  --font-family-sans: 'Roboto Flex', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  --font-family-primary: var(--font-family-sans);

  --font-body-medium-1: var(--font-weight-500) var(--font-size-350)/var(--font-line-height-500) var(--font-family-primary);
}
```

And the following web component with an open shadow root.

```
// Web Component
:host {
  --font-family-primary: “Comic Sans MS”;
  font: var(--font-body-medium-1);
}
```

Any idea why the font shorthand does not accept any individual property overrides? Every test fails. If the font properties individual properties like font-family have custom properties as their values, the cascade doesn't happen.

Comment: From a glance, some of your (indented) custom properties declarations have wrong leading dashes: Em-dash (\u2014) will not work.

Comment: @myf Just the result of copying from a text doc. It's correct in code. I updated the code description.

Comment: Ok well now besides wrong quotes, aren't you supposed to do `font: var(--font-body-medium-1);` instead of `font: var(--font-family-primary);`? The later only sets font family and by definition resets all other font properties to implicit (initial) values.

Comment: Clearly I should have reviewed my code before I posted. Updated to medium-1, which is what I wanted to demonstrate.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT: Updated for correct answer**

The reason it isn't working is because in CSS, the property values are computed, and *then* the *computed value* is inherited. `--font-body-medium-1` was already computed in `:root`, so it's locked into using the custom vars that were also in `:root`. It can't see the overridden `--font-family-primary` because it can't reach down into a descendant to read that new value.

As proof, if you copy `--font-body-medium-1: var(--font-weight-500) var(--font-size-350)/var(--font-line-height-500) var(--font-family-primary);` directly into your `:host`, you'll see that the override *does* work. That's because now, `font-body-medium-1` is inhereting the other custom vars from `:root` but can see the new `--font-family-primary` value.

There is a **solution**. It would obviously be tedious to copy `--font-body-medium-1` everywhere you want to use it, so you can instead define the custom property on every element using the universal selector. You can also remove it from `:root` since it doesn't accomplish anything there.

```
// Global CSS
:root {
  --font-weight-500: 500;
  --font-size-350: 14px;
  --font-line-height-500: 20px;
  --font-family-sans: 'Roboto Flex', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  --font-family-primary: var(--font-family-sans);

  /*  --font-body-medium-1: var(--font-weight-500) var(--font-size-350)/var(--font-line-height-500) var(--font-family-primary);  */
}

* {
  --font-body-medium-1: var(--font-weight-500) var(--font-size-350)/var(--font-line-height-500) var(--font-family-primary);
}
```

```
// Web Component
:host {
  --font-family-primary: “Comic Sans MS”;
  font: var(--font-body-medium-1);
}
```

**Old answer**

The `font` shorthand must provide values for *at least* `font-size` and `font-family` (and in that order). Your code isn't working because you're only providing a value for the font family—put a font size before it and it should work fine. E.g. `font: 16px var(--font-family-primary);`.

You can read more about the specifics in the documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font (just look at the **Syntax** section).

Comment: That was an oversight in my example that I have corrected. The problem is I expected font: var(--font-body-medium-1); to have --font-body-medium-1 properties expanded in place so that they could be overriden. That does not seem possible. I'm guessing it has something to do with the order the properties are hoisted/parsed, but I cannot find any mention in any spec about this order.

So it seems the only option is to completely redefine --font-body-medium-1 and change the desired sub property.

Comment: @Runicode I understand now—it was hard to tell what was actually going on with all the edits. Fortunately, there is a solution to the actual problem you're describing, and I've updated my original answer to include it.